# Sql script to disable all triggers who's name has AduitDelete

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Our live database has a trigger that populates a table with whos done what to the database. This is overkill for our development db. Is there a way I can write a sql script that will disable all triggers within a database whos name contains AuditDelete,AuditUpdate,AuditInsert? It mustn't disable it if it doesn't match this criteria

Comment: The answer is "Yes, there is a way".  If you want helpful answers please show some things you have tried and why they have not had the success you expected.  For example have you tried using Goggle?

Answer (score 1):

A way you could do it is have SQL return the queries to run. Then copy and paste them and execute. An upside is you can see what it is going to disable and can save the result set so you know exactly what you did.

Basically the query gets the trigger name and the name of the table it is on. You may need to tweak this as I just wrote it on the fly to help get you started.

```
SELECT 
    'DISABLE TRIGGER ' + tr.name + ' ON ' + p.name
FROM 
    sys.objects tr
    JOIN sys.objects p on tr.parent_object_id = p.object_id
WHERE 
    tr.type = 'TR'
    AND (tr.name LIKE '%AuditDelete%' 
        OR tr.name LIKE '%AuditUpdate%' 
        OR tr.name LIKE '%AuditInsert%')
```

If you run the query above it'll make more sense when you see the result set.